# Usage of MySQL's "IF EXISTS"

Tags: mysql

Here are two statements that I'd like to work, but which return error messages:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM gdata_calendars WHERE `group` =  ? AND id = ?) SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0
```

and

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gdata_calendars WHERE `group` =  ? AND id = ?) > 0)  SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0;
```

The question marks are there because I use parametrized, prepared, statements with PHP's PDO. However, I have also tried executing this with data manually, and it really does not work.

While I'd like to know why each of them doesn't work, I would prefer to use the first query if it can be made to work.

Comment: Hi there, what's the error message that you are getting?

Comment: For both of them: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You cannot use IF control block OUTSIDE of functions.  So that affects both of your queries.

Turn the EXISTS clause into a subquery instead within an IF function

```
SELECT IF( EXISTS(
             SELECT *
             FROM gdata_calendars
             WHERE `group` =  ? AND id = ?), 1, 0)
```

In fact, booleans are returned as 1 or 0

```
SELECT EXISTS(
         SELECT *
         FROM gdata_calendars
         WHERE `group` =  ? AND id = ?)
```

Comment: Is it possible to execute another query on Boolean value returns.?

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi what does `SELECT EXISTS` returns, `bool`, I need to check record existence in C++?

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi perfect!

Answer (score 35):

I found the example **RichardTheKiwi** quite informative.

Just to offer another approach if you're looking for something like `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 ..) THEN ...`

-- what I might write in MSSQL

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table WHERE FieldValue='')
BEGIN
    SELECT TableID FROM Table WHERE FieldValue=''
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE(FieldValue) VALUES('')
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS TableID
END
```

-- rewritten for MySQL

```
IF (SELECT 1 = 1 FROM Table WHERE FieldValue='') THEN
BEGIN
    SELECT TableID FROM Table WHERE FieldValue='';
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table (FieldValue) VALUES('');
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS TableID;
END;
END IF;
```

Comment: The MySQL portion of this answer does not appear to work.

Comment: MySQL always returns value if we use this code - It's not working as expected.

Comment: If the question is about `mysql`, why do you provide a solution for `mssql`?

Comment: MySQL says: Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF" at position 0)

Comment: Is there any way to avoid queryng  the same statement twice ?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works well and one can also just use the

```
If Exists (...) Then ... End If;
```

syntax in Mysql procedures (if acceptable for circumstance) and it will behave as desired/expected. Here's a link to a more thorough source/description: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99120/if-exists-then-update-else-insert

One problem with the solution by @SnowyR is that it does not really behave like "If Exists" in that the (Select 1 = 1 ...) subquery could return more than one row in some circumstances and so it gives an error.  I don't have permissions to respond to that answer directly so I thought I'd mention it here in case it saves someone else the trouble I experienced and so others might know that it is not an equivalent solution to MSSQLServer "if exists"!

Answer (score 0):

If your table has an auto-incrementing primary key, you can use `REPLACE INTO ... VALUES`

```sql
SELECT @id := id FROM tableName WHERE fieldName='criteria value' LIMIT 1;
REPLACE INTO tableName(id, fieldName, col1, col2)
VALUES (@id, 'criteria value', 'value1', 'value2')
```

If the select statement returns `NULL`, then a new row is inserted.
Otherwise, if a row is found, it will update the row with key `@id`.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT IF((
     SELECT count(*) FROM gdata_calendars 
     WHERE `group` =  ? AND id = ?)
,1,0);
```

For Detail explanation you can visit [here](http://www.easysolutionweb.com/mysql-tutorials/mysql-if-function?stack=)