# If exists in mysql not working

Tags: mysql, if-statement, exists

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pages.id = 21)
UPDATE `pages` SET `content`='Updated' WHERE (`id`='21')
ELSE
INSERT INTO `pages` (`subject_id`) VALUES ('102')
```

Not Working 
What is the problem

Comment: Is it inside function? If not then you can't use `IF EXISTS` as control structure, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 INSERT INTO `pages` (`subject_id`) VALUES ('102')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `content`='Updated' 
 WHERE `id`='21'
```

Comment: Agree with the idea assuming id is a unique field, but put id in the field list of the insert , and put the id value of 21 into the values.