# check existance of record in table row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to test whether record for particular condition exist or not.

```
$con = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'mysql');            

        if ($con->query("select count(*) from userpost  where userid = 1000004") != null) 
        {
            echo "exist";
        }
        else        
        { 
            echo "not exist";
        }
```

is this correct way?

or let me know if anything better

Comment: `IF EXISTS`; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists

Comment: @AlexK.: I already saw it. but it could not work for me. it directly checks `SELECT IF( EXISTS(
             SELECT *
             FROM gdata_calendars
             WHERE `group` =  ? AND id = ?), 1, 0)` without showing connection parameter.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
if ($con->query("select user_id from userpost  where userid = 1000004 LIMIT 1 ") != null) 
        {
            echo "exist";
        }
        else        
        { 
            echo "not exist";
        }
```

Comment: thanks,  but always shows `exist` even if userid does not exist

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best way assuming that `userid` is the primary key.  You can't get much better performance than a primary key in the where clause (assuming no joins, unions, etc exist).

Comment: userid is not primary key. And above code echo `exist` even of no such id present

Comment: Lets tag this with php to draw some extra attention

Answer (score 0):

$con->query will never equals *null*. as said in php manual. [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries
>   mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries
>   mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Use fetch_row to get row from query result. [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)

```
$con = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'mysql');            

$result = $con->query("select exists( select * from userpost where userid = 1000004 )");

if ( $result !== FALSE )
{
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    if( $row[0] != 0 )
    {
        echo 'exists';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'not exist';
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'error';
}

$result->close();
```