# IF EXISTS MySQL syntax error, but each line works individually

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database in place with a couple thousand promo codes, and I need something implemented where when a worker goes to get an ID it will check their ID if it is already assigned to a promo code, will return it, if there ID is not in the system will return the next promo code in the queue. This code I have now works each line individually but not as whole. I feel like its a simple error but I need a second pair of eyes looking onto it

`IF EXISTS(select promo_code from Promo where worker_id='ABC123')
    select promo_code from Promo where worker_id='ABC123'
ELSE
    insert into Promo(worker_id) values('ABC123')
    where Id=count(worker_id)+1`

Sample Data

`Id   worker_id    promo_code
0    ABC123       1234567890
1                 1928374657
2                 9184373462`

So if ABC123 was passed it would return me 1234567890, but if I passed it DEF456, it would then see DEF456 is not in the table, insert it in the table at Id=1

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense to me.  Can you provide some sample data and what you want to accomplish?

Comment: He is trying to INSERT/UPDATE where not exists?

Comment: You IF syntax is wrong. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is T-Sql, I read the question too fast and didn't notice that OP was using MySQL.

You need to begin and end when using an if statement.

```
IF EXISTS(select promo_code from Promo where worker_id='ABC123')
BEGIN
  select promo_code from Promo where worker_id='ABC123'
END
ELSE
  insert into Promo(worker_id) values('ABC123')
    where Id=count(worker_id)+1
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

**Don't ask me why begin and end only go around the if part; I have no clue why the else doesn't need it also...

Comment: Still getting error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if EXISTS(select promo_code from Promo where vendor_id='ABC123') BEGIN selec' at line 1"

Comment: Oops, my bad, this is T-Sql that I posted. I read the question too fast.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for an `update`, not an `insert`.  You can do the update as:

```
update table t
    set worker_id = 'ABC123'
    where not exists (select * from (select 1 from table t2 where worker_id = 'ABC123') t) and
          worker_id is null
    order by id
    limit 1;
```

Then return the value you want is:

```
select promo_code
from table t
where worker_id = 'ABC123';
```

In the `update`, the `not exists` is essentially saying "don't do anything if the worker id is already in the table".  The double subquery is to get around a quirk of MySQL.  I would also recommend a unique index on `worker_id`, because you do not seem to want duplicates in the table:

```
create unique index table(worker_id);
```

Once the record is updated, you can fetch the value using the `select`.

Comment: Getting error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table `Promo` where `worker_id` = 'ABC123')) and `worker_id` is null ' at line 3

Comment: @user3273370 . . . That MySQL trick requires a table alias as well.