# Insert Into table If similar value exists in another existing table (not a foreign key)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert, exists

I'm trying to insert an "Item order" in a table called AsksFor and I want to make sure the Item and ItemManufacturer exists in the table Sells. However I keep getting "syntax error, unexpected if, expecting END_OF_INPUT or ';'" for using the IF. Anyone know any other ways to write this for MySQL?

```
INSERT INTO AsksFor (Username, ItemName, ItemManufacturer)
VALUES ('Harish', 'zkoxtlv93', 'tbzrt93')
IF EXISTS(SELECT ItemName, ItemManufacturer
        FROM Sells
        WHERE Sells.ItemName = VALUES(ItemName)
        AND Sells.ItemManufacturer = VALUES(ItemManufacturer));
```

Comment: you might wanna take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EXISTS clause is not availaible for MySQL . Anyways you don't need it , the AND condition in WHERE clause performs the checking part whether values exists in source table `Sells`.

Try this

```
INSERT INTO AsksFor (Username, ItemName, ItemManufacturer)
SELECT DISTINCT 'Harish',ItemName, ItemManufacturer
        FROM Sells
        WHERE ItemName='zkoxtlv93' AND ItemManufacturer='tbzrt93'
```