# Insert new SQL row only if there is same value from other table

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I'm having,

Table1:

```
ID  |   DEVICEID    |  STATUS  |
--------------------------------
1   |   SN001       |  ENROLL  |
2   |   SN002       |  ENROLL  |
```

Table2:

```
ID  |   DEVICEID    |  STATUS  |
--------------------------------
1   |   SN001       |  ENROLL  |
2   |   SN002       |  ENROLL  |
3   |   SN003       |  ENROLL  |
4   |   SN004       |  ENROLL  |
```

There is a form to fill up in order to insert new DEVICEID and STATUS in Table1 using AJAX POST to PHP. Before update the SQL, how do I create a condition where Table1 only **can be updated if only there is *same*** DEVICEID filled up in form with DEVICEID in Table2 else it will return error and will not update the Table1.

Here's what I have:

```
"SELECT deviceid
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.deviceid=table2.deviceid
INSERT INTO table1(deviceId,status)
VALUES('$deviceid', '$status')
WHERE deviceid = deviceid";                 <--- Not sure what I'm doing here, trying to compare
```

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: am using mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (deviceid, status)
SELECT DISTINCT '$deviceid','$status'
FROM table2
WHERE deviceid='$deviceid' AND status='$status'
```

Thanks to: [Insert Into table If similar value exists in another existing table (not a foreign key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926726/insert-into-table-if-similar-value-exists-in-another-existing-table-not-a-forei)

And everyone who helped me. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT DEVICEID, STATUS
FROM Table2
WHERE DEVICEIUD = @param1 AND STATUS = @param2
LIMIT 1

SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

And check number of row effected

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with two queries

```
"SELECT EXISTS (
  SELECT deviceid
  FROM table1
  INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.deviceid=table2.deviceid
)"
```

then if you're using `PDO` check if the `rowCount is == 0` like this

```
if ($stmt->rowCount == 0) {
    "INSERT INTO table1(deviceId,status)
     VALUES('$deviceid', '$status')
     WHERE deviceid = deviceid
    ";
} else {
    echo "Device ID already exists.";
}
```

keep in mind, using `SELECT EXISTS ()` will only return `0` or `1`, So you won't be able to get any data, If you want to return some data you can go with

```
SELECT deviceid
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.deviceid=table2.deviceid
LIMIT 1
```

Also if you was going to get the data while using `PDO` Then use `rowCount()` instead of `fetchColumn()`