# Mysql query IFEXIST does not return any result

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a login form in PHP. i am passing the username and password that user had entered and check weather that exist in the data base.

i have done the coding, but IF EXIST query does not return any result.

can any one help me to fix this. or give me a alternate idea.. Thank you...

```
        <?php

        $name= $_POST["usname"];
        $pass = $_POST ["password"];

        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","sathya","sathya","learning1"); 
        //mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO user (name, password) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$pass."')");
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "IF EXISTS(SELECT *  FROM  user  WHERE name='".$name."'AND password='".$pass."')");
        mysqli_close($connection);

        echo "result ".$result;

        if($result == True){

          header("Location: logedin.php");
            //redirect_to('logedin.php');
        }else{

            echo "not logged in installed";
        }


        ?>
```

Comment: you close your connection.

Comment: i tried without closing the connection also, it does not work.

Comment: There's no such thing as `IF EXISTS`, there's only `SELECT IF ...`

Comment: try to use mysqli_fetch_array to compare your result

Comment: The first entry in Google by searching "IF EXISTS mysql".

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say anything about the PHP part, but the query will surely result in a syntax error.

`IF whatever ...` is only allowed in stored procedures or functions, not in single queries. You can however replace the `IF` with `SELECT` like

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT *  FROM  user  WHERE name='".$name."'AND password='".$pass."')");
```

This query would return either 0 (if no entry exists) or 1 (if an entry exists). It's also a good idea to use `EXISTS` as it stops the query as soon as an entry was found and does not return the whole dataset.

Answer (score 4):

This is a late answer, but there are a few things you need to be made aware of. (Not taking away from the accepted answer).

You will need to use `if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)` because your query will always be TRUE if the username matches and the password does NOT, and vice-versa.

You are better off using [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) rather than using `if($result == True)`

***Sidenote:*** Consult my footnotes regarding password storage and SQL injection.

```
<?php
$DB_HOST = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";

$db = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
    if($db->connect_errno > 0) {
      die('Connection failed [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
    }

$name = $_POST["usname"]; // See footnotes about this
$pass = $_POST ["password"]; // See footnotes about this

$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT *  FROM  users  WHERE username='".$name."' AND password='".$pass."')");

// Works just as well
// $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM  users  WHERE username='".$name."' AND password='".$pass."'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "Both match.";
    }

    else{
    echo "Sorry, there was not a perfect match.";
    }
```

---

**Footnotes:**

You can also use:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM  users  WHERE username='".$name."' AND password='".$pass."'");
```

Which does the same for `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT *` while using less characters.

or choose actual columns:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT username, password FROM  users  WHERE username='".$name."' AND password='".$pass."'");
```

I suggest that you use prepared statements and sanitize your inputs. Not doing so will leave you open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

Here are a few tutorials on (mysqli) prepared statements that you can study and try:

- [**Tutorial one**](http://webdevtuts.co.uk/simple-mysqli-tutorial/#more-41)
- [**Tutorial two**](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/PHP-5:-MySQLi-Prepared-Statements/41452)
- [**Tutorial three**](http://www.phpmysqlitutorials.com/2011/04/16/mysqli-whats-the-difference-between-standard-queries-and-prepared-statements/)

Here are a few tutorials on PDO:

- [**PDO tutorial one**](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)
- [**PDO tutorial two**](http://crewow.com/PHP-PDO-to-Connect-MySQL-Database.php)
- [**PDO tutorial three**](http://www.w3resource.com/php/pdo/php-pdo.php)

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you are storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this beside using 'IF EXISTS' function--

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT *  FROM  user  WHERE name='".$name."'AND password='".$pass."'");



$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)  // $count=1 if any row is present with mathing username and pwd in db
{
    echo "user already logged in";
}
else  
{
  echo "user not exist";
}
```

Comment: You select everything just to do a count on the result afterwards to see if there's at least one entry? LOL

Comment: This `mysql_num_rows` should be `mysqli_num_rows` --- You can't mix two different MySQL APIs.