# Insert if record not exists else delete in mysql with a long query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a follow system that allow user to follow one another. I'm using php pdo so it doesn't support multiple line query instead I need a long query. Currently I'm using the code below

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT id FROM follow WHERE user1 = 'kim' AND user2 = 'tim' ");
if($query->rowCount() > 0 ){
    $db->query("DELETE * FROM follow WHERE user1 = 'kim' AND user2 = 'tim' ");
}else{
    $db->query("INSERT INTO follow (user1,user2) VALUES ('kim','tim') ");
}
```

So here what I want is a long query rather than multiple query statement. Additional with the long query I need get the data that indicate wether the record is insert or delete.(Maybe this question is duplicated but this is the part that wasn't duplicated) How can I acheive it?

Comment: What do you consider a `long query`?

Comment: @u_mulder mean that just one line of query rather the thing I currently doing like using EXISTS, NOT EXISTS etc

Comment: without get the result from first query its not possible to put `if else` condition ?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is to insert and delete sub-query in one query based on a condition. You might want to take a look at this : [EXISTS](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/exists.php)

Comment: Can't your UI tell whether or not the user is following or unfollowing? Seems not very user friendly to have the user click on something without knowing whether it does one thing or the exact opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the "long query"

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT id FROM follow WHERE user1 = 'kim' AND user2 = 'tim' )
BEGIN
    DELETE * FROM follow WHERE user1 = 'kim' AND user2 = 'tim'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO follow (user1,user2) VALUES ('kim','tim')
END
```

If it gets too "long" put it in a stored procedure.

Comment: Does the code above can return either insert or delete to me?

Comment: According to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5528932/630530), this answer won't work.

Comment: @WayneSmallman the answer you linked is right, but it does not make mine wrong :)