# MySql if else statement, if not valid in this position

Tags: mysql

I have a vet table and a medical table with a 1 to many relationship, and the ID's are auto incremented.

```
CREATE TABLE vet(
      vetID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      vetPractice varchar(35),
      Address varchar(150),
      contactNumber varchar (15),
      PRIMARY KEY (VetID)
      );


CREATE TABLE medical(
      medicalID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      medication VARCHAR (200),
      PRIMARY KEY (medicalID),
      FOREIGN KEY (vetID) REFERENCES vet(vetID)
      );
```

Users can enter details of a vet, i want a query to determine;

- if the the vet details entered already exist, then update the foreign key in vetID(medical) with the entered vetID.
- else if the vet does not exist create a new vet and update the foreign key in vetID(medical) with the newly created vetID.

I have the following query

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM vet WHERE vetPractice = "inputValue") 
    THEN
    UPDATE medical set value vetID = (Select max(vetID) from vet)
    ELSE 
    INSERT INTO vet values (null, "newVetPractice", "NewAddress", "newContactNumber", "NewEmergencyNumber" );
    Then
    update  medical set value vetID = (Select max(vetID) from vet);
END IF;
```

However, i am not familiar with if else's in mySQL is this the correct format, i have seen somethings about stored procedures.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Is this query in a stored procedure - IF - ELSE is only valid there. Also your syntax is incorrect - the last "Then" is not required. This may be relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really clear about your logic; but it seems like you wanted it in a stored procedure format.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 'sp_Med' (IN 'in_vetPractice' VARCHAR(35))  
LANGUAGE SQL  
NOT DETERMINISTIC  
CONTAINS SQL  
SQL SECURITY DEFINER  
BEGIN
    DECLARE ckExists int;  
    SET ckExists = 0;  

    SELECT count(*) INTO ckExists from vet WHERE vetPractice = in_vetPractice;   

    IF (ckExists > 0) THEN 
        UPDATE medical SET vetID = (Select max(vetID) FROM vet WHERE vetPractice = in_vetPractice) 
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO vet VALUES (NULL, "newVetPractice", "NewAddress", "newContactNumber", "NewEmergencyNumber");
        UPDATE medical SET vetID = LAST_INSERT_ID();    
    END IF; 
END;
```

Execute it like

```
CALL sp_Med('newPractice')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to update your query, and this is the general syntax you have to use rather tha n yours:-

```
INSERT INTO `tableName` (`a`,`b`,`c`) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `a`=VALUES(`a`), `b`=VALUES(`b`), `c`=VALUES(`c`);
```

This query will insert records if they are not present, and on presence it will update them.

So use this rather than your approach