# IF EXISTS statement giving error #1064

Tags: mysql, database, if-statement, exists

Can't seem to get a simple if exists statement to work in mysql, is there a possible reason why it simply will not work???

```sql
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Cookies WHERE VALUED ='2601:2c0:8403:5320:947e:a047:6e0f:e23a')
BEGIN
THEN
END;
    UPDATE Cookies SET Amount = Amount + '1' WHERE VALUED ='2601:2c0:8403:5320:947e:a047:6e0f:e23a'

ELSE 
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Cookies (Valued, Amount) Values ('2601:2c0:8403:5320:947e:a047:6e0f:e23a', '1' )
END;
```

Comment: IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Cookies WHERE VALUED ='2601:2c0:8403:5320:947e:a047:6e0f:e23a')
BEGIN
THEN
END;
    UPDATE Cookies SET Amount = Amount + '1' WHERE VALUED ='2601:2c0:8403:5320:947e:a047:6e0f:e23a'

ELSE 
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Cookies (Valued, Amount) Values ('2601:2c0:8403:5320:947e:a047:6e0f:e23a', '1' )
END;
END IF;

Comment: edit your question don't post code in comment  .. code in comment is unreadable ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists

Answer (score 2):

Delete all BEGIN and END - you don't need them and you've used them incorrectly anyway:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Cookies WHERE VALUED ='2601:2c0:8403:5320:947e:a047:6e0f:e23a') THEN
    UPDATE Cookies SET
    Amount = Amount + '1'
    WHERE VALUED ='2601:2c0:8403:5320:947e:a047:6e0f:e23a'
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO Cookies (Valued, Amount) Values 
    ('2601:2c0:8403:5320:947e:a047:6e0f:e23a', '1' );
END IF;
```

If `VALUED` is the primary key, you can do it much simpler:

```
insert into Cookies (Valued, Amount) values 
('2601:2c0:8403:5320:947e:a047:6e0f:e23a', 1 )
on duplicate key update Amount = Amount + 1;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Cookies
WHERE VALUED ='2601:2c0:8403:5320:947e:a047:6e0' at line 1

Comment: @caleb you can't just execute it as a stand alone query. An `IF` must be in a stored procedure.

Comment: How to use this query with out using stored procedure. Simple execution.

Comment: @amee if `VALUED` is the primary key you can - see edited answer

Comment: Thanks sir, but i dont want to update value if there exists id in table. I just want to give the infromation. e.g. PRINT ' ID already EXISTS.'

Comment: @Amee either create a unique index on the column (easiest and best, because it covers all types of data changes - ie insert or update), or `... on duplicate key signal sqlstate '1234' message_text = 'ID already exists'`

Comment: - on duplicate key signal sqlstate '1234' message_text = 'ID already exists' .. This isn't working.

Comment: That means we have no any option  ?

Comment: @Amee I would `create unique index idx1 on mytable(mycolumn)`. It will cause an sqlexception if someone tries to insert a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have messed up the order of the `then` and `begin` keywords:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Cookies WHERE VALUED ='2601:2c0:8403:5320:947e:a047:6e0f:e23a')
THEN -- Here!
BEGIN
    UPDATE Cookies SET Amount = Amount + '1' WHERE VALUED ='2601:2c0:8403:5320:947e:a047:6e0f:e23a'
END;    
ELSE 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Cookies (Valued, Amount) Values ('2601:2c0:8403:5320:947e:a047:6e0f:e23a', '1' )
END;
```

EDIT:
Assuming `valued` is a primary (or even just a unique) key, it would be easier to use an insert statement with an `on duplicate` clause:

```
INSERT INTO cookies (valued, amount)
VALUES ('2601:2c0:8403:5320:947e:a047:6e0f:e23a', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount = amount + 1;
```

Comment: That still doesn't make sense...  `THEN BEGIN END UPDATE ELSE`?  Surely the `UPDATE` should be before the `END` rather than after?

Comment: @MatBailie yikes! Got caught up in the cop-and-bug... It should, of course, be then-begin-update-end-else-insert-end (edited and fixed).

Comment: Much appreciated, that will fulfill my needs, still would like to understand why mysql will not ingest an if exists statement, I cannot find a lot of documentation on it, and was hoping someone could decipher it for me, but thanks again, saved me  a lot of time!