# error with IF EXISTS ()

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Products WHERE name='Iphone1' AND manufacturer='appl') THEN
      INSERT INTO Products(product_id, name, category, manufacturer) 
         VALUES (10000, 'IphoneZ', null, 'appl');
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF" LINE 1: IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
>   FROM Products WHERE name='Iphone1' A...

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Double quotes instead of single?

Comment: read the manual
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: Googling your title and 'mysql': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

MySQL only supports the `IF` *statement* in programming blocks -- stored procedures, functions, and triggers.  Hence you cannot do what you want that way.

Instead, you can just write a single query:

```
INSERT INTO Products (product_id, name, category, manufacturer)
    SELECT product_id, name, category, manufacturer
    FROM (SELECT 10000 as product_id, 'IphoneZ' as name, null as category, 'appl' as manufacturer) t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Products p WHERE p.name = t.name and p.manufacturer = t.manufacturer);
```

Actually, though, it is best to have the database directly enforce this sort of uniqueness.  You can do so with a unique constraint/index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_product_manufacturer_name ON product(manufacturer, name);
```

Then you can write an query to ignore errors by doing:

```
INSERT INTO Products (product_id, name, category, manufacturer)
    VALUES (10000, 'IphoneZ', null, 'appl')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE category = VALUES(category);
```

The `ON DUPLICATE KEY` doesn't do anything -- it just serves to avoid returning an error if a duplicate value is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing END IF keyword at the end of IF statement. And also, this SQL statement can be only used in a Routine block such as Stored Procedure or Stored Function.

Your SQL should be like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Products WHERE name='Iphone1' AND manufacturer = 'appl') THEN
  INSERT INTO Products(product_id, name, category, manufacturer) 
  VALUES (10000, 'IphoneZ', null, 'appl');
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it MySQL or SQL server?
2. I think you type wrongly :  name='Iphone1' . It should be 'IphoneZ'.
3. You used single quotes in some places and double quotes in some places.

If it is mysql then try below query
INSERT INTO Products(product_id, name, category, manufacturer) 
 SELECT * FROM (select 10000,'IphoneZ', null, 'appl') AS tmp_table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Products_arun WHERE name='IphoneZ'
 AND manufacturer='appl') LIMIT 1;

If it is SQL server then try below query
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product WHERE name='IphoneZ' AND manufacturer='appl')
INSERT INTO product(product_id, name, category, manufacturer) 
VALUES (10000, 'IphoneZ', null, 'appl');