# Update or Insert with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table structure as follows:

```
Id(PK AI) | DataField1(Varchar) | DataField2(Varchar) | User_Id(int)
1         | abc                 | xyz                 | 12
2         | sdj                 | mnu                 | 09
3         | yjf                 | pku                 | 17
4         | anx                 | vby                 | 11
```

I want to insert or update this table.

Let's say I want to insert data as `DataField1='wer', DataField2='try'
 where User_Id = 11`, provided that a record with given `User_Id` does
 not exist. If a record with `User_Id=11` exists then update the record.

I want a single query and not multiple queries.

Please keep in mind that `User_Id` is not unique. `Id` is Primary key with Auto increment so I'm not touching that field.

I want something which is similar to 'on duplicate key update'. To my knowledge, this query has no 'where condition'.

Comment: Check `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: @Rahul That can't be used if you don't have a unique index.

Comment: @JohnP That requires a unique index.

Comment: You can't do this in a single query if you don't have a unique key on `User_Id`. The only way to do both insert and update in a single query is with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, and that requires a unique key.

Comment: @Barmar, my guess is that `User_Id` column is FK column and thus would be having a unique secondary index on it and so it's fine.

Comment: @Rahul The question says "`User_Id` is not unique." And a FK doesn't have to be unique. If you have a many-to-many relationship, FK is not unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you said you want a single query, but that's not possible if the `User_Id` column isn't unique. You can do it with the following two queries:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET DataField1='wer', DataField2='try'
WHERE User_Id = 11;

INSERT INTO yourTable (DataField1, DataField2, User_Id)
SELECT 'wer', 'try', 11
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE User_Id = 11)
```

The `WHERE` clause in the second query makes the `SELECT` query return an empty result when the user ID already exists in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below code for update and insert If Id exists : 

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM yourTable WHERE User_Id = @User_Id)
BEGIN
     UPDATE yourTable SET DataField1='wer', DataField2='try'
     WHERE User_Id = @User_Id 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO yourTable (DataField1, DataField2, User_Id)
   SELECT  'wer', 'try', @User_Id
END

IN MYSQL :

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 
        'password_protected_version') 
THEN 
     UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='2.2.2' WHERE option_name = 
     'password_protected_version'; 
ELSE 
     INSERT INTO wp_options (option_value, option_name) SELECT '2.2.2', 
     'password_protected_version'; 
END IF;
```

Comment: MySQL objected to "IF EXISTS" with the following error: "Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF EXISTS" at position 0)"

I don't have time to dig into it much, but guessing it's related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists

Comment: @SarahLewis,Please post your sql query.

Comment: Here's the SQL: IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'password_protected_version')
BEGIN
 UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='2.2.2'
 WHERE option_name = 'password_protected_version' 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO wp_options (option_value, option_name)
 SELECT '2.2.2', 'password_protected_version'
END

Comment: @SarahLewis, I updated my answer.Check that answer for mysql.