# Can't find syntax error in simple sql command

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been looking at this for a while and i can't find the syntax error.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ElpasoTable WHERE elapsoCommand = 'shouldRunWlapon')
BEGIN
END
```

Comment: You cannot use `IF... BEGIN ... END` in a query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for MySQL

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ElpasoTable WHERE elapsoCommand = 'shouldRunWlapon') THEN
---- YOUR CODE HERE
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Valid commands..

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS...`,`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS..`

You cannot use `IF EXISTS` simply in a mysql command.

for your need you can try this instead

perfect solution for your case

[usage of `IF EXISTS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5528932/6659373)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know what output u want but here is the suggestion.
We can't use directly if exists statement.
We can use it after certain commands such as delete ,update ,Create etc.
First if u want the desired output,remove if exists.
So the query will be (  SELECT * FROM ElpasoTable WHERE elapsoCommand = 'shouldRunWlapon')
 If ur table has column named elapsocommand and value is shouldRunWlapon,,then the Elapsocommand table is displayed.

U can use some concepts between begin and end statements based on ur requirement.
They are stored procedures , triggers, views etc