# Synatx error near 'IF EXISTS'

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to solve an error.
While i am exicuting this query i met with an error.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM category_info WHERE category_name = 'Electronics')
BEGIN
select * from category_info;
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
     insert into category_info(category_name) values('Electronics');
END
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM category_info WHERE category_name =
>   'Electronics') BEG' at line 1

I need help,Thanks in advance

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of MySQL's "IF EXISTS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists)

Comment: I can't solve my error

Comment: Are you using this code in a stored program (procedure,function or trigger)?

Comment: Yes.that's the mistake.I solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved by using procedure.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Check_exists(IN categoryName  varchar(20))
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM category_info WHERE category_name = categoryName)
THEN 
    SELECT 'Already Exists' as status;
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO category_info(category_name) VALUES(categoryName); 
END IF;
END $$
```

and this procedure can be called by

```
call Check_Exists('Electronics');
```

It will display message "Already exists " if it is exists or else it will insert a row.