# Java/MYSQL unknown column in field set

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I know there are many questions regarding this issue but I still haven't found a solution for my problem.
I build a PreparedStatement in and pass variables but the error (**Unknown column 'checkedAt' in 'field list'**) is persistent.

My code:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `suites` WHERE name = ?) 
THEN INSERT INTO `suites` (`name`, `description`, `metaData`, `active`, `checkedAt`, `createdAt`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
ELSE UPDATE `suites` SET `name` = ?, `description` = ?, `metaData` = ?, `active`= ?, `checkedAt` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `name`= ?; END IF;");
stmt.setString(1, suite.get("SuiteName"));
...
stmt.setInt(9, 1);
stmt.setString(10, suite.get("SuiteName"));
stmt.execute();
```

The column `checkedAt` is available in the database and filled. The issue appears only in the UPDATE part (ELSE clause) of the statement.

Does anyone can provide me a solution? 
Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists

Comment: You might want to use [`insert .. on duplicate key update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: The update function worked until I inserted the "checkedAt" identifier. The code with out this field works perfectly and as wanted.

Comment: can be close, the issue was caused by a trigger in the background which was throwing this error.