# How to perform this mysql query correctly?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

I'm using the npm module 'mysqljs' and trying to perform a query via it.

The purpose of it is to check whether a certain constraint or foreign key exists and to drop it if it does.

Unfortunately I get the following error and can't figure out what's wrong:

> **Error:** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (
>       SELECT * 
>       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS ' at line 1

The code looks as followed (shortened version of course):

```
const query = `
  IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS 
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE "Location_User";
  ) THEN
    ALTER TABLE Location DROP CONSTRAINT Location_User;
  END IF
  `

connection.query(query, (error, results) {
  if (error) throw error;
  return results
});
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5528932/11921403) might be of help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of MySQL's "IF EXISTS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists)

Comment: @popcorn That won't work for a DDL statement.

Comment: You need to put this code in a stored procedure, you can't use `IF` statements in ordinary queries. The alternative is performing the two queries separately, with the `if` logic in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `IF` statements outside of stored procedures.

Do the logic in JavaScript instead.

```
connection.query(`SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
                  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS 
                  WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE "Location_User";`, (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  if (results[0].count > 0) {
    connection.query('ALTER TABLE Location DROP CONSTRAINT Location_User;', (error) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    });
  }
});
```