# Sequelize: Check if table exist and empty

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I want check a table and if table is empty create a record.

my code:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const About = sequelize.define("About",
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
                autoIncrement: true,
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
            },
            title: DataTypes.STRING(150),
            content: DataTypes.TEXT("medium"),
        },
        {
            freezeTableName: true,
            timestamps: false,
        },
    );

    About.findAll()
    .then(about => {
        if (about.length === 0) {
            About.create({
                title: "About Us",
                content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
            });
        }
    });

    return About;
};
```

But when table doesn't exist I get this error:

> Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `content` FROM `About` AS `About`;
>
> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Table 'mydb.about' doesn't exist

how can I handle this issue?

Comment: Take a look at [usage-of-mysqls-if-exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists)

Comment: Thanks but I want a solution with Sequelize.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that

Comment: you can try to call describeTable of QueryInterface (to get QI call getQueryInterface in sequelize) to get information about a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my problem.

I added `.sync()` and create table before find. Both of `.findOrCreate()` and `.findAll()` is working.

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const About = sequelize.define("About",
        {
            title: DataTypes.STRING(150),
            content: DataTypes.TEXT("medium"),
        },
        {
            freezeTableName: true,
            timestamps: false,
        },
    );

    About.sync();

    About.findOrCreate({
        where: {id: 1},
        defaults: {
            title: "About Us",
            content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
        },
    });

    return About;
};
```