# SQL Trigger to update OLD value in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a `trigger` to simultaneously update a different `table` than the one I have updated, with the same data.

I have two different database with the same tables and i'm trying to sync them, when i insert, update or delete data from one, i want to do automaticaly the same to the other table, with triggers.

This is the trigger code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`Ivan_test`@`%` TRIGGER `Prueba_Ivan`.`mag_articulos_PI_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `mag_articulos_PI` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.Prueba_Ivan.mag_articulos_PI NOT IN (SELECT * FROM ivan_test.mag_articulos_IT) THEN
    INSERT INTO ivan_test.mag_articulos_IT 
            VALUES (new.xempresa_id, new.xarticulo_id, new.xcategoria_id, new.xvisible_web, new.xnovedad,new.xpromocion,new.ximagen_prelim,new.ximagen_amp,new.xtexto1,new.xtexto2,new.xtexto3,new.xtexto4,new.xtexto5);
    ELSE 
    UPDATE ivan_test.mag_articulos_IT SET OLD.ivan_test.mag_articulos_IT = NEW.Prueba_Ivan.mag_articulos_PI;    
    END IF;
END
```

but I have this error:
`Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'OLD.Prueba_Ivan' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery`

Can someone help me to find the mistake?

Thank you!!

Comment: Where are the table definitions? What is `OLD.Prueba_Ivan.mag_articulos_PI` a reference to?

Comment: You can access OLD. values but you cannot update them...

Comment: There is no need to qualify a column with a table name - which is what I assume you are trying to do here - OLD.Prueba_Ivan.mag_articulos_PI and if you did I guess as with everything else in sql table name would come first..Also there is no evidence that you are setting delimiters or any way of understanding if you do need to set them given that you have not told us if you are using a wizard in workbench.

Comment: @Scratte OLD.Prueba_Ivan.mag_articulos_PI reference the database Prueba_ivan, table mag_articulos_PI before update. 

I am trying to check if the row to update is in the other table, if it is not, I add it.

Comment: I do not think you can reference a database this way. I think MySQL expects the old value to be a column that is on the table `mag_articulos_PI` of the trigger. In addition to the table definitions, it would greatly help if you explained in words what you are trying to do and if you have several databases if you're trying to update data across those.

Comment: @P.Salmon I need to reference the table this way because I have two different databases, i think the problem is when i try to access to the table before to apply changes. I don't know how i can check if this row is in the other table too.

Comment: Just to be clear a trigger is ON a table in the session DB and You can reference OLD. and/or NEW. columns on the table the trigger is on. You can insert or update to another DB table but you cannot amend OLD.  or NEW. values in that DB table (they don't exist)

Comment: @Scratte true, i'm going to try explain it better in the description.

Comment: I see you have updated your post. But what are the names of the databases, the names of the tables? The clarifications that you have made in comments, should go into your post. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Scratte Great, thanks for your help. I'll keep the post updated.

Answer (score 0):

## OLD.Prueba_Ivan.mag_articulos_PI

`OLD` is an alias to the triggered row. Your `trigger` applies to `Prueba_Ivan`, which means that `OLD` and `NEW` are representing your `Prueba_Ivan` record before the change, and after it, respectively. This means that when you intend to reference `mag_articulos_PI`, you will need to do it via `OLD.mag_articulos_PI`, so remove the tablename from that expression.

## OLD.ivan_test.mag_articulos_IT

As mentioned in the previous section, here `OLD` is an alter-ego of the updated `Prueba_Ivan` record, you do not need it in order to reference `ivan_test`.

## Further explanation

An expression of the form of

```
a.b.c
```

reads as follows:

In database a, table b, column c. When you do something of the like of

```
OLD.t.c
```

it reads: In the OLD database, table t, column c.

Comment: Thank you, i'm gonna try. How can i check if the row to modify is in the other table? Maybe i have to do it on a trigger before update?

Comment: @ImvD you are looking for If-exists. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists