# How do I create a stored procedure that select from one table based on condition in another table

Tags: sql, ssms

For Example, I have 2 tables.

Table A has Setting/isActive

Table B has Name/Ages/City

So I want to retrieve records from B only when isActive = 1 for Setting ='GetThis' in Table A

something like

```
if 'GetThis' = 1 from table A
then get records from table B
```

Comment: Get what records from B? there does not appear to be a relationship between A and B

Comment: get all records from B, it doesn't matter what records, and there is no relationship between A and B, but I want get records from B if condition in A is true

Comment: @Pandakkk, does Table A has column name too? based on your question above,  `if 'GetThis' = 1 from table A` What records from Table B should it gets?

Comment: Please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists try something and if you get into difficulty post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllRecords
@isActive BIT
SET @isActive = (Select isActive FROM TableA WHERE Setting = 'GetThis')

AS

IF @isActive = 1
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM TableB

END
GO;
```

Comment: Cool, but published code is sql-server/MSSQL not mysql.. Glad I didn't waste time writing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which DBMS you're using, but look into the command `IF EXISTS`

Answer (score 0):

If it should get all records from table B, you can try this;

```
Select b.name, b.ages, b.city from table_B b, table_A a where a.isActive = 1 and a.Setting ='GetThis'
```